# How can I update software such as Chrome or Edge on my Azure Virtual Machines automatically?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, software-update

Since we have a large number of Azure VMs, it is very time-consuming to connect to each machine and manually update software.
Is there a way to do this either automatically or at least centrally for multiple VMs?

For Windows Server 2019 updates, we use our Automation Account for update management.

Thanks for your support.

Nick

Comment: Not automatically, but you can uninstall/install programs with PowerShell. Do you have the ability to run PowerShell scripts on a schedule, in Azure DevOps for instance?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @joelforysh we can not update automatically.

you can use Mange engine desktop central or SCCM to Schedule the software updates.

[Reference](https://%20https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/azure-agent-installation.html)